# Applying a Fast Coordinate Transformation in Python

Tags: python, numpy, grid, transform, coordinate

I have a simple 2x2 transformation matrix, **s**, which encodes some liner transformation of coordinates such that **X' = sX**.

I have generated a set of uniformley distributed coordinates on a grid using the **np.meshgrid()** function and at the moment I traverse each coordinate and apply the transformation at a coordinate by coordinate level. Unfortunately, this very slow for large arrays. Are there any fast ways of doing this? Thanks!

```
import numpy as np

image_dimension = 1024
image_index = np.arange(0,image_dimension,1) 
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(image_index,image_index)

# Pre-calculated Transformation Matrix.
s = np.array([[ -2.45963439e+04,  -2.54997726e-01], [  3.55680731e-02, -2.48005486e+04]])

xx_f = xx.flatten()
yy_f = yy.flatten()

for x_t in range(0, image_dimension*image_dimension):

    # Get the current (x,y) coordinate.
    x_y_in = np.matrix([[xx_f[x_t]],[yy_f[x_t]]])

    # Perform the transformation with x.
    optout =  s * x_y_in

    # Store the new coordinate.
    xx_f[x_t] = np.array(optout)[0][0]
    yy_f[x_t] = np.array(optout)[1][0]

# Reshape Output
xx_t = xx_f.reshape((image_dimension, image_dimension))
yy_t = yy_f.reshape((image_dimension, image_dimension))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loops are slow in Python. It is better to use [vectorization](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-for-data/9781449323592/ch04.html).
In a nutshell, the idea is to let numpy do the loops in C, which is much faster.

You can express your problem as matrix multiplications **X' = sX**, where you put all the points in **X** and transform them all with just one call to numpy's dot product:

```
xy = np.vstack([xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
xy_t = np.dot(s, xy)
xx_t, yy_t = xy_t.reshape((2, image_dimension, image_dimension))
```

Comment: @kazemakase I was timing your answer, and I found it to be much faster than mine, apparently `vstack` is much faster than any combination of `array(list)` and passing directly the list. Do you have any idea why is that?

Comment: @NoelSegura I guess that is due to my use of `ravel` instead of your `flatten`. If I read the docs correctly, `flatten` always creates a copy of the array, while `ravel` tries to create a view.

Comment: @kazemakase, `ravel` is slightly faster than `flatten` but `vstack` seems to be the biggest factor. I tried both ways, `np.dot(s,np.vstack([xx.ravel(),yy.ravel()]))` is slightly faster than `np.dot(s,np.vstack([xx.flatten(),yy.flatten()]))`. But `np.dot(s,np.vstack([xx.ravel(),yy.ravel()]))` is much faster than `np.dot(s,[xx.ravel(),yy.ravel()])`

Comment: @NoelSegura Funny, on my machine the `vstack` version is slightly slower.

Comment: @kazemakase, really, that is weird. Can you please try this code? http://pastebin.com/6BPu8mAa

Comment: `array ravel` is fastest, closely followed by `vstack ravel`: http://imgur.com/gallery/BBV1PAl

Comment: @kazemakase wow, that is really different from what I got, http://imgur.com/2cnziT4 , I wonder what could be the difference

Comment: I have not tried this chat-thing before, but I'll do so now... after all our discussion is slightly tangential to the question :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101790/discussion-between-kazemakase-and-noel-segura).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the numpy `dot` function to get the dot product of your matices as:

```
xx_tn,yy_tn = np.dot(s,[xx.flatten(),yy.flatten()])

xx_t = xx_tn.reshape((image_dimension, image_dimension))
yy_t = yy_tn.reshape((image_dimension, image_dimension))
```

Which is much faster